# Размер блока Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Учусь верстать через Bootstrap, но не могу понять где задается высота блока. Где её изменять? Вот например: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]`

```
    <div class="col-md-3 ">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/500x300" alt="" >
            <div class="caption">
                <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, soluta, eligendi doloribus sunt minus amet sit debitis repellat. Consectetur, culpa itaque odio similique suscipit</p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" role="button">Full Story</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/500x300" alt="">
            <div class="caption">
                <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, soluta, eligendi doloribus sunt minus amet sit debitis repellat. Consectetur, culpa itaque odio similique suscipit</p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" role="button">Full Story</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/500x300" alt="">
            <div class="caption">
                <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, soluta, eligendi doloribus sunt minus amet sit debitis repellat. Consectetur, culpa itaque odio similique suscipit</p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" role="button">Full Story</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading c-list">
                <span class="title">Block 3</span>
            </div>


            <ul class="list-group" id="contact-list">
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                        <img src="http://api.randomuser.me/portraits/men/97.jpg" alt="Scott Stevens" class="img-responsive img-circle" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                        <span class="name">Scott Stevens</span>
                        <br/>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker text-muted c-info" data-toggle="tooltip" title="5842 Hillcrest Rd"></span>
                        <span class="visible-xs"> <span class="text-muted">5842 Hillcrest Rd</span>
                        <br/>
                        </span>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone text-muted c-info" data-toggle="tooltip" title="(870) 288-4149"></span>
                        <span class="visible-xs"> <span class="text-muted">(870) 288-4149</span>
                        <br/>
                        </span>
                        <span class="fa fa-comments text-muted c-info" data-toggle="tooltip" title="scott.stevens@example.com"></span>
                        <span class="visible-xs"> <span class="text-muted">scott.stevens@example.com</span>
                        <br/>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                        <img src="http://api.randomuser.me/portraits/men/97.jpg" alt="Seth Frazier" class="img-responsive img-circle" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                        <span class="name">Seth Frazier</span>
                        <br/>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker text-muted c-info" data-toggle="tooltip" title="7396 E North St"></span>
                        <span class="visible-xs"> <span class="text-muted">7396 E North St</span>
                        <br/>
                        </span>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone text-muted c-info" data-toggle="tooltip" title="(560) 180-4143"></span>
                        <span class="visible-xs"> <span class="text-muted">(560) 180-4143</span>
                        <br/>
                        </span>
                        <span class="fa fa-comments text-muted c-info" data-toggle="tooltip" title="seth.frazier@example.com"></span>
                        <span class="visible-xs"> <span class="text-muted">seth.frazier@example.com</span>
                        <br/>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                        <img src="http://api.randomuser.me/portraits/women/90.jpg" alt="Jean Myers" class="img-responsive img-circle" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                        <span class="name">Jean Myers</span>
                        <br/>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker text-muted c-info" data-toggle="tooltip" title="4949 W Dallas St"></span>
                        <span class="visible-xs"> <span class="text-muted">4949 W Dallas St</span>
                        <br/>
                        </span>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone text-muted c-info" data-toggle="tooltip" title="(477) 792-2822"></span>
                        <span class="visible-xs"> <span class="text-muted">(477) 792-2822</span>
                        <br/>
                        </span>
                        <span class="fa fa-comments text-muted c-info" data-toggle="tooltip" title="jean.myers@example.com"></span>
                        <span class="visible-xs"> <span class="text-muted">jean.myers@example.com</span>
                        <br/>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                        <img src="http://api.randomuser.me/portraits/men/24.jpg" alt="Todd Shelton" class="img-responsive img-circle" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                        <span class="name">Todd Shelton</span>
                        <br/>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker text-muted c-info" data-toggle="tooltip" title="5133 Pecan Acres Ln"></span>
                        <span class="visible-xs"> <span class="text-muted">5133 Pecan Acres Ln</span>
                        <br/>
                        </span>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone text-muted c-info" data-toggle="tooltip" title="(522) 991-3367"></span>
                        <span class="visible-xs"> <span class="text-muted">(522) 991-3367</span>
                        <br/>
                        </span>
                        <span class="fa fa-comments text-muted c-info" data-toggle="tooltip" title="todd.shelton@example.com"></span>
                        <span class="visible-xs"> <span class="text-muted">todd.shelton@example.com</span>
                        <br/>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                        <img src="http://api.randomuser.me/portraits/men/49.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive img-circle" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                        <span class="name">Rosemary Porter</span>
                        <br/>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker text-muted c-info" data-toggle="tooltip" title="5267 Cackson St"></span>
                        <span class="visible-xs"> <span class="text-muted">5267 Cackson St</span>
                        <br/>
                        </span>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone text-muted c-info" data-toggle="tooltip" title="(497) 160-9776"></span>
                        <span class="visible-xs"> <span class="text-muted">(497) 160-9776</span>
                        <br/>
                        </span>
                        <span class="fa fa-comments text-muted c-info" data-toggle="tooltip" title="rosemary.porter@example.com"></span>
                        <span class="visible-xs"> <span class="text-muted">rosemary.porter@example.com</span>
                        <br/>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End row -->
```

`

Comment: Высота блока зависит от содержимого. Bootstrap ее автоматически никак не регулирует (пока). Вы можете воспользоваться `css` для установления нужных Вам значений: `height`, `max-height` и т.д.

Comment: @cyadvert, Bootstrap3 не регулирует. А в Bootstrap4 уже есть CardGroups и CardDesks

Comment: @Oceinic да, Вы правы. Однако он пока только в альфа тестировании (кажется), так что новичкам его лучше не советовать :) Вот я его и не упомянул...

Answer (score 2):

Задайте блоку height и будет Вам счастье

Comment: Почему ширину? width?

Comment: сорри, обшибся:)